# Figure out which .proto for a message

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a sample of a ProtoBuf encoded message, as well as all of the `.proto` files. I know that the message is one of the messages in the proto files. Is there some way to figure out which message fits the encoded message?

Comment: Inspection? Heck, if the number of candidates is small: trial and error. There is a way of using "protoc" to show an estimate of the internal structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no.  The protobuf format is dense, and the same bytes may be valid as two different kinds of messages.

That said, you can pipe the message to `protoc --decode_raw` to see the content with numeric tags.  From there, you might be able to manually compare it against each type to decide whether it makes sense as that type.